# Purpose behind declaring ArrayList as double or any

Tags: java, arraylist

I am beginner level in JAVA,

I have seen some JAVA Code has been like this:

```
ArrayList<Double> aldb = new ArrayList<Double>();
```

As ArrayList is heterogeneous collection , to make it  homogeneous do we need to create with data type, OR What else could be possibilities?

Just to understand Masters perspective.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If anyone is doing `ArrayList aldb= new ArrayList();`, then they are stuck back in Java 1.4. Java 5 added *generics*, and you should always use generics when working with collections, e.g. if you want the list to contain `double` values, you write  `ArrayList<Double> aldb= new ArrayList<Double>();`, which is a homogeneous list, given that it can only store `Double` values

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what the code looks like, but `ArrayList<double>` is not allowed, because `double` is not a class but a primitive type.  `ArrayList<Double>` would be correct.  Also, if you really want a heterogeneous list that can contain any type, use `ArrayList<Object>`.  Don't use raw `ArrayList` types (without the `<>`) unless absolutely necessary, which is probably never.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at Generics in Java. This allow you to specify a particular type.
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-generics/index.html

```
ArrayList<String> aldb = new ArrayList<String>();
```

If you try to add  any object other than of String in this case, then that will be a compiler error. String is just an example, you can specify whatever type you would like.